# How do I programmatically check to see if a python package is installed on a remote Linux machine?

Tags: python, linux

I have a bunch of Linux build slaves that use Python to run automated test for each build.  Each python environment requires a specific list of modules to be installed (some requiring specific versions as well).  I am trying to write a python script that will go to each machine and check to see if a list of python packages are installed or not as well as checking versions of several packages.  I have this working for the local machine but looking for suggestions on the best way to check a remote machine.

For reference, on the local machine I'm using this in a try/except to check to see if the module is installed

```
pkg_resources.get_distribution(module)
```

and this to check the particular version

```
pkg_resources.get_distribution(module).version
```

Any suggestions on the best way to do this for a remote system?

Comment: Ssh? Paramiko? Ansible?

Comment: We are using ssh and paramiko packages already.
Linux is not my forte' and Python is not that much better so looking for a list of steps.

Comment: I'd suggest reading over ansible documentation, then if your python isn't very good

Comment: Ansible is nice but don't think it would fit what we are looking to do.  We have a working script for local machine and looking to extend that for remote systems

Comment: This would be a usecase for virtual environments and a requirements file.

Comment: You can use ansible to scp file copy, then use the command module to run it. It'll return the output as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've SSH'd into the machine, `pip freeze` and `grep` should work for finding if the module is installed.

Further reading: http://blog.revathskumar.com/2011/10/python-list-all-packages-installed.html

As for SSHing, the subprocess library should allow you to run these commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any shell commands via ssh:

```
$ ssh your_login@your_server which python
/usr/bin/python
```

This should be sufficient to examine what's installed on the remote server.

Comment: I need to do this from a Python script.  This should automatically connect to each system in turn and verify installed packages

Comment: You can run `ssh` from Python, either with `subprocess` or with one of the many wrapper libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using paramiko I created an SSH connection
executed pip freeze
searched the returned list for the packages I need to verify

Answer (score 0):

If you use [requirements files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) to install the packages, you might want to look into the [compare-requirements](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/compare-requirements/0.2.1) package.

As for being able to run it remotely, you should be able to achieve that with SSH as AetherUnbound suggested